# Laravel Echo not receiving Pusher events in React

Tags: reactjs, websocket, pusher, laravel-echo

Edit: forgot to add **bootstrap.js**

I'm trying to setup websockets using Pusher and Laravel-Echo but I'm running into a strange bug. I can see that my events are being fired on the Pusher debugger console but I'm not receiving the events on my frontend. Here is my code to setup Pusher:

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,
});
```

**broadcast.php**

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true
            ],
        ],
```

**app.php**

```
/*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
```

**OptionChange.php** (this is my Event I'm listening for)

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\ItemInstance;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class OptionChange implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $instance;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ItemInstance $instance)
    {
        $this->instance = $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('itemInstance' . $this->instance->id);
    }

    // return this info in Pusher
    public function broadcastWith() {
        return [
            'id' => $this->instance->id,
            'answer' => $this->instance->answer,
            'question_number' => $this->instance->question_number
        ];
    }
}
```

React Code (where I'm listening for my event)

```
// set up channel listener for live updates
    componentDidMount() {
        const { started, studentId } = this.state

        if (!started) {
            window.Echo.channel('studentStartedTest' + studentId)
                .listen('StartTest', (didStart) => {
                    console.log('startTest')
                    if (didStart) { 
                        this.setState({ started: true })
                    }
                })
        } else {
            // window.Echo.leaveChannel('studentStartedTest' + studentId)
            window.Echo.channel('itemInstance' + this.props.id)
            .listen('OptionChange', (instance) => {
                console.log('change')
                this.setState({ answer: instance.answer })
            })


        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm trying a `console.log` whenever my event fires. Unfortunately the console.log never gets run.

I've also tried to change `implements ShouldBroadcast` to `implements ShouldBroadcastNow` but that didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Your laravel event is going to broadcast using the full class name with namespaces. To have a cleaner event name that matches what you are actually listening to add the `broadcastAs` method to your `OptionChange` Event class

```
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'StartTest';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't notice this in the Laravel documentation

If you customize the broadcast name using the broadcastAs method, you should make sure to register your listener with a leading . character

So if your broadcastAs() function looks like this

```
 public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'StartTest';
    }
```

Your JS listen will need to be

```
window.Echo.channel('studentStartedTest' + studentId)
                .listen('.StartTest', (didStart) => {
                    console.log('startTest')
                    if (didStart) { 
                        this.setState({ started: true })
                    }
                })
```